# how to define my-own style in android.widget.Spininer

Tags: android, layout, styles, spinner

i wanna to display a `imageview` and a `textview` in my  pull-down list of `Spinner`.

such as `[ ImageView(the image of Mr.Green) , TextView(the name of Mr.Green) ].`i

hava little thought about the question,but i can't make it.Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Create custom Adapter with text and imageview:

```
public class CustomSpinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
int image[];
String[] text;
LayoutInflater inflter;

public CustomAdapter(Context applicationContext, int[] image, String[] text) {
    this.context = applicationContext;
    this.image = image;
    this.text = text;
    inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return flags.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.spinner_item_layout, null);
    ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.spImageView);
    TextView names = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.spTextView);
    icon.setImageResource(image[i]);
    names.setText(text[i]);
    return view;
}
```

}

Then set this adapter to the spinner:

```
CustomSpinnerAdapter adapter = new CustomSpinnerAdapter(this, YourImageArray, YourTextArray);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here is the layout for each spinner item (spinner_item_layout.xml):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/spTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/spImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>"

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: i'm a green hand,so,what the differences between the layout:spinner_value_layout and spinner_item_layout.in other words, how to write spinner_value_layout,what this layout is?i'm puzzed.er.......

Comment: I've edited the answer, this is simpler than before. Please give me a feedback.

Comment: yep,i've made it.it's useful.cuz the mechanism of this website,i'can't votes for you untill i receive 15 reputation.thanks again.